# Build Stackdriver Dashboard that contains a filtered list of log entries

Tags: elastic-stack, dashboard, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

We are evaluating Stackdriver as an alternative to our [ELK-stack](https://www.elastic.co/what-is/elk-stack), I'm missing a few features that I have in kibana ([1](https://www.elastic.co/what-is/elk-stack)).

Most important I don't find a way to show the actual logs in a Stackdriver Dashboard, I can only show graphs based on the logs. Changing between two tabs all the time ([2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYr98.png) and [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skwhl.png)) and adapting the filters on both of them seems very inconvenient for log/error analysis.
Is there a way that I can have a dashboard that also shows logs (based on the filters in the dashboard search)?

[image: kibana dashboard]
[image: stackdriver logs]
[image: stackdriver dashboard]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no way to show raw log files in the Metrics Dashboard unfortunately.

You can file a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com) to add this functionality to Stackdriver.

Comment: Thx for the answer, I will leave the question open for a while, maybe there is a hack or an idea how to work around this